# How to get Google Indexed pages count via PHP

Tags: php, json, google-api

Hello I am trying to create a script that should retrieve a count with all indexed pages from Google. Only the count of total pages (the results from site:$domain)

I found this script:

```
function getGoogleCount($domain) {
$content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
$data = json_decode($content);
return intval($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
}
```

But this API is old and gives different count, so is any other way to get the indexed pages count?

Thanks

Comment: You could use [Google's webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) which could provide you with a number of pages they have indexed on your site.  You can go a step further and provide Google with a sitemap XML file that will assist in making sure the googlebot knows what to index.

Comment: If you are trying to get data about a site you control, then @Crackertastic is correct. If you are trying to create a service which will allow you or others to get data about third party sites then that API is probably the best way to do it. The `estimatedResultCount` is rounded but they're not going to make more specific data available. You said it "gives different count". What are you comparing it to?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to provide a service for third party sites. The problem with the actual api is for example if I search an url gives me `estimatedResultCount:200;` but the real result if I search on https://www.google.com/search?q=domain.com is 1700...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
function getpageindexed($name){
$weburl="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:".$name."&filter=0";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $weburl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
if($data['responseStatus']==200)
return $data['responseData']['cursor']['resultCount'];
else
return false;
}

$name="domainname.com"; //your domain name
echo getpageindexed($name); //get indexed page
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but actually check this: For example if I type http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:stackoverflow.com the `resultCount` is 8.000.000, but if you check via google search (https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=site:stackoverflow.com) the result is 30,400,000 so what is the real count ?